# AWS Cloudsearch Uploading Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to upload json object to the AWS Cloudsearch. Here's my entire code for creating the index fields:

```
  require 'aws-sdk'
  require 'pp'

  class CloudSearch
    @@client = Aws::CloudSearch::Client.new({region: 'us-east-1',credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('KEY', 'SECRET')})
    def self.create_index_fields
      Aws.config.update({
        region: 'us-east-1'
      })

      client = @@client
      fields = {'id' => 'metadata',
                'name' => 'search',
                'rating' => 'sort',
                'review_count' => 'sort',
                'price' => 'sort',
                'category_name' => 'search/filter',
                'rank_in_category' => 'sort',
                'brand_name' => 'search/filter',
                'award_winner' => 'filter'
              }
      fields.each do |key, value|
        options = {}
        indexFields = value.split("/")
        options[:domain_name] = "dev-purchxapp-com"
        options[:index_field] = {}
        options[:index_field][:index_field_name] = key
        type = :text_options
        if key == "price"
          options[:index_field][:index_field_type] = "double"
          type = :double_options
        elsif key == "review_count" || key == "rating"
          options[:index_field][:index_field_type] = "int"
          type = :int_options
        else
          options[:index_field][:index_field_type] = "literal"
          type = :literal_options
        end      
        options[:index_field][type] = {}
        if indexFields.include?('search')
          options[:index_field][type][:search_enabled] = true
        end
        if indexFields.include?('sort') || indexFields.include?('filter')
          options[:index_field][type][:facet_enabled] = true
        end
        options[:index_field][type][:return_enabled] = true

        res = client.define_index_field(options)
        pp(res)
      end
    end

    def self.list_index_fields
      client = @@client
      res=client.describe_index_fields({
        domain_name: "dev-purchxapp-com"
      })
      res
    end

    def self.delete_index_field(field)
      client = @@client
      res = client.delete_index_field({
        domain_name: "dev-purchxapp-com", # required
        index_field_name: field, # required
      })
    end

    def self.delete_all_index_fields
      client = @@client
          fields = {'id' => 'metadata',
                'name' => 'search',
                'rating' => 'sort',
                'review_count' => 'sort',
                'price' => 'sort',
                'category_name' => 'search/filter',
                'rank_in_category' => 'sort',
                'brand_name' => 'search/filter',
                'award_winner' => 'filter'
              }
      fields.each do |key, value|
        res = client.delete_index_field({
          domain_name: "dev-purchxapp-com", # required
          index_field_name: key, # required
        })
      end
    end

    def self.create_cloudsearch_domain
      client = @@client
      res = client.create_domain({domain_names: ["dev-purchxapp-com"]})
    end

    def self.list_cloudsearch_domains
      res = @@client.describe_domains({domain_names: ["dev-purchxapp-com"]})
    end

    def self.index_documents
      res = @@client.index_documents()
    end
  end
```

When the create_index_fields is ran from the rails console it shows that the fields are created, but when I go to upload documents it says it cant find the fields with the different field names that I define.

defining a hash to turn into a json object:

```
    def cloudsearch_product_json
      fields = {}
      fields[:award_winner] = !self.consumr_approved_at.nil? ? 1 : 0
      fields[:brand_name] = !self.brand.nil? ? self.brand.name.to_s : ""
      fields[:category_name] = !self.category.nil? ? self.category.name.to_s : ""
      fields[:description] = ""
      fields[:id] = self.id
      fields[:name] = self.name
      fields[:price] = self.price.to_s
      fields[:rank_in_category] = self.rank_in_category.to_s
      fields[:rating] = self.rating
      fields[:review_count] = self.review_count

      data = {}
      data[:type] = "add"
      data[:id] = "product-#{self.id }"
      data[:fields] = fields
      data
    end
```

And the document upload rake task:

```
    require 'aws-sdk'
    require 'pp'

    namespace :cloud_search do
      task :index_all_products => :environment do
        Aws.config.update({
          region: 'us-east-1', access_key_id: 'KEY', secret_access_key: 'SECRET'
        })
        client = Aws::CloudSearchDomain::Client.new(endpoint:AppConfig.cloud_search_host)
        product = "[#{Product.first.cloudsearch_product_json.to_json}]"
        resp = client.upload_documents({documents: product, content_type: "application/json",})
      end
    end
```

and finally my error:

```
    Aws::CloudSearchDomain::Errors::DocumentServiceException: { ["Field "award_winner" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "brand_name" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "category_name" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "description" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "id" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "name" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "price" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "rank_in_category" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "rating" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "review_count" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)"] }
```

Am I forgetting to initialize something or what's going on? Any help would be much appreciated. Hopefully I've given you enough to go off of to be able to help me figure it out. I've been reading the AWS SDK docs for a couple weeks trying to figure this one out and have had no luck. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudSearch/Client.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html

Thanks for your help

Here's what I get listing my index fields in the AWS CLI:

```
C:\Users\ndalton>aws cloudsearch describe-index-fields --domain-name dev-purchxa
pp-com
{
    "IndexFields": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:54:00.568Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 200,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:47.629Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "award_winner"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:59.962Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 199,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:46.704Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "SearchEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "brand_name"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:58.440Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 197,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:45.556Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "SearchEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "category_name"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T21:11:20.083Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 73,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-12T21:58:32.590Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "SearchEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "description"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:54.808Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 192,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:41.349Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "id"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:55.684Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 193,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:42.233Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "SearchEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "name"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:57.682Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 196,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:44.738Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "DoubleOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "double",
                "IndexFieldName": "price"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:59.214Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 198,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:46.145Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "LiteralOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "literal",
                "IndexFieldName": "rank_in_category"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:56.494Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 194,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:43.476Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "IntOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "int",
                "IndexFieldName": "rating"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": false,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:53:57.158Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 195,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:08:44.008Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "IntOptions": {
                    "FacetEnabled": true,
                    "ReturnEnabled": true
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "int",
                "IndexFieldName": "review_count"
            }
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "PendingDeletion": true,
                "State": "RequiresIndexDocuments",
                "CreationDate": "2015-08-11T20:22:56.541Z",
                "UpdateVersion": 201,
                "UpdateDate": "2015-08-18T15:11:34.982Z"
            },
            "Options": {
                "TextOptions": {
                    "AnalysisScheme": "_en_default_"
                },
                "IndexFieldType": "text",
                "IndexFieldName": "testfield"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My hard coded JSON file looks like this:

```
     [{"type":"add","id":"product-1","fields":{"award_winner":0,"brand_name":"","category_name":"","description":"","id":1,"name":"CNSMRBLKHL","price":"","rank_in_category":"","rating":"4.67","review_count":3}}]
```

And the error stays the same:

```
C:\Users\ndalton>aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url http://doc-dev-purchxapp-c
om-rjxkouy2hppztmth47dn2oowua.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com upload-documen
ts --content-type application/json --documents \\OGDC1\og-users\ndalton\Document
s\test.json

A client error (DocumentServiceException) occurred when calling the UploadDocume
nts operation: { ["Field "award_winner" does not exist in domain configuration (
near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "brand_name" does no
t exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id produc
t-1)","Field "category_name" does not exist in domain configuration (near operat
ion with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "description" does not exist in
 domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Fie
ld "id" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; doc
ument_id product-1)","Field "name" does not exist in domain configuration (near
operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "price" does not exist in
 domain configuration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Fie
ld "rank_in_category" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation wit
h index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "rating" does not exist in domain conf
iguration (near operation with index 1; document_id product-1)","Field "review_c
ount" does not exist in domain configuration (near operation with index 1; docum
ent_id product-1)"] }
```

Comment: 1) If those are your real AWS keys, edit the post ASAP. 2) Check in the AWS web console -- do you see your fields there? 3) What you have here is pretty complicated and that's going to make debugging harder. Try simplifying, eg by defining a hardcoded json document (generate it by printing the json you currently send) and uploading that through the AWS web console -- does it work?

Comment: Thank you I edited the key and secret. Right now I do not have access to the AWS web console. All I was given is the access key and secret for it.

Comment: You can verify your schema with the AWS CS CLI tools from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/cloudsearch-command-line-tools.html and then run  `cs-describe-domain --show-all`. It sounds like your index is missing a bunch of fields so there's likely a problem with how you're creating it, but it would be food to confirm that.

Comment: I added my cmdline stuff

Comment: Your fields are all in the state `"State": "RequiresIndexDocuments"` but they should be `State": "Active"`. This should be solved by re-indexing your domain --  `aws cloudsearch index-documents --domain-name dev-purchxapp-com` as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/indexing.html .

Comment: Will you post that as an answer so I can give you a vote and accept it. That worked for me thanks.

Comment: Glad that worked! Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-index your domain in order to make the newly-added fields active. They're currently showing as `"State": "RequiresIndexDocuments"` but should be in `"State": "Active"`.

Running `aws cloudsearch index-documents --domain-name dev-purchxapp-com` should solve the problem. For more about indexing your domain, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/indexing.html